# Error 13 - Type mismatch - Index Match

Tags: vba, excel

Getting the above error on the Index/Match.  Will try and keep this short and sweet but I am a VBA noob.  Everything that is called has data in.  One thing I noticed was that RefCol (a range of numbers) has leading and trailing whitespace when I do a Debug Print.  However when I tested the length of the value it returned the correct values.

I can't understand what is breaking it, I did an index match in the workbook itself and it works perfectly.

```
Private Sub Ref_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = Worksheets("Details")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Call_Log")

Dim RefCol As Range
Dim NameCol As Range
Dim PhoneCol As Range
Dim DateCol As Range

Set RefCol = tbl.ListColumns("Ref Number").DataBodyRange
Set NameCol = tbl.ListColumns("Caller Name").DataBodyRange
Set PhoneCol = tbl.ListColumns("Telephone").DataBodyRange
Set DateCol = tbl.ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange

Me.CallDate.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(DateCol, Application.Match(Me.Ref.Value, RefCol, 0))

End Sub
```

Have I set this up correctly?

Thanks

Evan

Comment: What is CallDate and what value does the formula return?

Comment: RefCol needs to be a single column. Same with DateCol or you can add a column index numver to Index.

Comment: Likely the late-bound `Match` call is *returning* some `#VALUE!` error value, and since that type can't be coerced to anything it makes the early-bound `Index` call *raise* a type mismatch error. Replace `Application.Match` with `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` to make it *raise* an error in case of a mismatch, and/or pull it out and compute it separately, and only invoke the `Index` when you *know* the `Match` succeeded.

Comment: CallDate is a text box in a UserForm, is this the problem?  The way I want it to work is that you select the reference and then it displays the call data (date, caller, phone number) in boxes on the form - is this impractical/impossible?  Thanks

Comment: @Jeeped - they are single columns in my table, I don't know how to check if this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

As stated most likely the Match is not being found and an error is being passed to the INDEX.

Pull the MATCH out and test for the error before finding the correct cell in the data.

```
Private Sub Ref_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = Worksheets("Details")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Call_Log")

Dim RefCol As Range
Dim NameCol As Range
Dim PhoneCol As Range
Dim DateCol As Range

Set RefCol = tbl.ListColumns("Ref Number").DataBodyRange
Set NameCol = tbl.ListColumns("Caller Name").DataBodyRange
Set PhoneCol = tbl.ListColumns("Telephone").DataBodyRange
Set DateCol = tbl.ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange

Dim mtchRow As Long
mtchRow = 0
On Error Resume Next
    mtchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ref.Value, RefCol, 0)
On Error GoTo 0
If mtchRow > 0 Then
    Me.CallDate.Value = DateCol.Cells(mtchRow, 1).Value
Else
    MsgBox "'" & Me.ref.Value & "' not found, or lookup array is more than one column or row"
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, I have tried this and it returns -  '7' not found, or lookup array is more than one column or row.  I know that the Ref numbers are there because I did a for to loop through and debug print them.  How would I go further and figure this out?  Thanks

Comment: Double check that your data does not have spaces or other non printable characters that would exclude Excel finding a match. The error now is with the data. Make sure that if you are looking for numbers that the data is not text strings that look like numbers. It is also looking for exact matches not partial matches