# Reference Lookup Equation VBA

Tags: vba, indexing, match, lookup

Hoping someone could help me out.  I have this one line of code that I cannot understand why it throws a *typemismatch* error.  What I am trying to accomplish is use index match to lookup a value and subtract, divide, add, ect. another value that is pulled with index match.  I have searched everywhere to see if there were any other similar questions with zero success.  I have been coding VBA for several years, but I am stumped on this for some reason.  If I take out the second lookup formula and the equation sign, the code runs correctly.  However, as soon as you add a minus, plus, or division sign, it errors out.  For ease, all variables are dimmed and set correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Code is below.  Thanks!

```
Dim qty as worksheet
Dim Imonth as integer, IImonth as integer
Dim lrow as long

With summary1
.Range("B3:B" & lrow).Formula =   Application.Iferror(Application.Index(qty.Columns(Imonth), Application.Match(.Range("A3:A" & lrow), qty.Columns(1), 0)) - Application.Index(qty.Columns(IImonth), Application.Match(.Range("A3:A" & lrow), qty.Columns(1), 0)), " ")
```

Comment: because unlike a formula on the sheet when an error is thrown in vba it stops.  so when the match is not found an error is passed to the INDEX and the INDEX does not know what to do with it so it throws that error.  You need to split the code apart and test for the error separately before passing to the INDEX.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283620/error-13-type-mismatch-index-match/49284552#49284552

Comment: Do you want the value, or do you want the formula in that cell?

Comment: I want the value to be calculated within each cell in the range, not a formula.  I know this can be done with formulaR1C1, however, it makes the program run very slow because the formulas are constantly updating.

Comment: then you will need to loop through each cell and assign the value from the code.  You will want to look at the link I provided.

Comment: I have ran each part separately and no errors are found.  If I run the reference lookup on the left side of the equation, it brings in the correct value.  If I run the reference lookup on the right side, it also brings in the correct value.  It will not calculate the difference between the two values.

Comment: You cannot input individual values into a mass range. You will need a loop.

Comment: You did just give me an idea with using a loop.  I could potential run the first reference lookup, then loop back through, taking the difference of the first value from the second reference value.  Thanks!

Comment: it is going to be quicker if you pull the match out separately and assign it to a variable.  Then used .Cells() instead of INDEX.

Comment: Could you provide a quick example, so I understand your suggestion better?

Answer (score 0):

I would load all into memory arrays and then loop that.

```
Sub kjlk()


Dim qty As Worksheet
Dim Imonth As Integer, IImonth As Integer
Dim lrow As Long
Dim summary1 As Worksheet

'assign the variables
Set qty = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set summary1 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Imonth = 20
IImonth = 21

lrow = 20

Dim IMArr As Variant
Dim IIMarr As Variant
Dim lkupArr As Variant

IMArr = Intersect(qty.Columns(Imonth), qty.UsedRange).Value
IIMarr = Intersect(qty.Columns(IImonth), qty.UsedRange).Value
lkupArr = Intersect(qty.Columns(1), qty.UsedRange).Value

Dim InArr As Variant
Dim OutArr As Variant



With summary1
    InArr = .Range("A3:A" & lrow).Value
    ReDim OutArr(1 To UBound(InArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(InArr, 1)
        Dim mtch As Long
        mtch = WhereContains(lkupArr, InArr(i, 1))
        If mtch > -1 Then
            OutArr(i, 1) = IMArr(mtch, 1) - IIMarr(mtch, 1)
        Else
            OutArr(i, 1) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next i
   .Range("B3:B" & lrow).Value= OutArr
End With
End Sub

Function WhereContains(arr, v) As Long
Dim rv As Long, i As Long
    rv = -1
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = v Then
            rv = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    WhereContains = rv
End Function
```

Comment: I will try this out.  Thanks for the help.  Sometimes its nice just to get other thoughts.